# "subreactions" with chemmacros reactions module

Tags: subequations, chemmacros

I would like to use something like subequations within the reactions environment provided by chemmacros.  Something like this:

A -> B  {1a}

B -> C  {1b}

C -> D  {1c}

This doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{modules=reactions}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{reactions}
A &-> B \\
B &-> C \\
C &-> D
\end{reactions}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to do this with chemmacro?  Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "This doesn't work" ? It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to make it a MWE.  This example labels the reactions {1}, {2}, {3}.  Not {1a}, {1b}, {1c}

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out.  You have to create a new environment `subreactions` based on the `subequations` environment that uses `reaction` instead of `equation` as the counter and `thereaction` instead of `theequation` as the tag:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\chemsetup{modules=reactions}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ignorespacesafterend}{\def\ignorespacesafterend{\global\@ignoretrue}}{}
\newenvironment{subreactions}{%
  \refstepcounter{reaction}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\thereaction}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{reaction}}%
  \setcounter{reaction}{0}%
  \def\thereaction{\theparentequation\alph{reaction}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{reaction}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
A &= B \\
B &= C \\
C &= D
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subreactions}
\begin{reactions}
A &-> B \\
B &-> C \\
C &-> D
\end{reactions}
\end{subreactions}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
A &= B \\
B &= C \\
C &= D
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subreactions}
\begin{reactions}
A &-> B \\
B &-> C \\
C &-> D
\end{reactions}
\end{subreactions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can safely remove the `\@ifundefined{ignorespacesafterend}` line.